# Extract text between HTML tags with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have HTML like this:

```
<h1> Header is here</h1>
  <h2>Header 2 is here</h2>
     <p> Extract me!</p>
     <p> Extract me too!</p>
  <h2> Next Header 2</h2>
     <p>not interested</p>
     <p>not interested</p>
  <h2>Header 2 is here</h2>
     <p> Extract me!</p>
     <p> Extract me too!</p>
```

I have a basic Nokogiri CSS node search returning <p> content but I can't find examples for how to target all text between the Nth closed H2 and the next open H2. I'm creating a CSV with the output so I would also like to read in a file list and put the URL as first result.

Comment: Please include sample code and examples of the desired output when you ask for help. It helps us help you.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489326/xpath-get-elements-that-are-between-2-elements

Comment: Thanks @Tin Man and Phrogz -- I had considered adding the code I had but it didn't approach a solution and wouldn't have helped. Phrogz -- looking at your examples here and at the link are re-directing my solution, very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

h = '<h1> Header is here</h1>
  <h2>Header 2 is here</h2>
     <p> Extract me!</p>
     <p> Extract me too!</p>
  <h2> Next Header 2</h2>
     <p>not interested</p>
     <p>not interested</p>
  <h2>Header 2 is here</h2>
     <p> Extract me!</p>
     <p> Extract me too!</p>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(h)

# Specify the range between delimiter tags that you want to extract
# triple dot is used to exclude the end point
# 1...2 means 1 and not 2
EXTRACT_RANGES = [
  2...3,
  4...5
]

# Tags which count as delimiters, not to be extracted
DELIMITER_TAGS = [
  "h1",
  "h2"
]

extracted_text = []

i = 0
# Change /"html"/"body" to the correct path of the tag which contains this list
(doc/"html"/"body").children.each do |el|

  if (DELIMITER_TAGS.include? el.name)
    i += 1
  else
    extract = false
    EXTRACT_RANGES.each do |cur_range|
      if (cur_range.include? i)
        extract = true
        break
      end
    end

    if extract
      s = el.inner_text.strip
      unless s.empty?
        extracted_text << el.inner_text.strip
      end
    end
  end

end

# Print out extracted text (each element's inner text is separated by newlines)
puts extracted_text.join("\n")
```

Comment: Thanks, Dan, this would have taken me a very long time to put together myself. Do you mind if I ask -- do you know how I can feed this script a list of html files?

Comment: @chuckfinley `files = ["path_to_file.html", ...]; files.each do |cur_file| h = File.open(cur_file, "r").read; ... end`

Comment: Dan, I can't make this work. I think its my unfamiliarity with ruby/nokogiri formatting. I'm going to post a new question so I can use formatting in my example. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can sometimes use NodeSet's & operator to get information between nodes:

```
doc.xpath('//h2[1]/following-sibling::p') & doc.xpath('//h2[2]/preceding-sibling::p')
```

Comment: thanks p, this is my first time with nokogiri, very useful to know there are many ways to skin this potato...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an XPath solution, here's a simple (naïve) implementation that assumes that the start and stop elements share the same parent and allows the XPaths for start and stop to be specified independently:

```
HTML = "<h1>Header is here</h1>
  <h2>Header 2 is here</h2>
     <p>Extract me!</p>
     <p>Extract me too!</p>
  <h2> Next Header 2</h2>
     <p>not interested</p>
     <p>not interested</p>
  <h2>Header 2 is here</h2>
     <p>Extract me three!</p>
     <p>Extract me four!</p>"

require 'nokogiri'    
class Nokogiri::XML::Node
  # Naive implementation; assumes found elements will share the same parent
  def content_between( start_xpath, stop_xpath=nil )
    node = at_xpath(start_xpath).next_element
    stop = stop_xpath && at_xpath(stop_xpath)
    [].tap do |content|
      while node && node!=stop
        content << node
        node = node.next_element
      end
    end
  end
end

html = Nokogiri::HTML(HTML)
puts html.content_between('//h2[1]','//h2[2]').map(&:content)
#=> Extract me!
#=> Extract me too!
puts html.content_between('//h2[3]').map(&:content)
#=> Extract me three!
#=> Extract me four!
```

Answer (score 2):

If the start and stop elements have the same parent, this is as simple as a single XPath. First I'll show it with a simplified document for clarity, and then with your sample document:

```
XML = "<root>
  <a/><a1/><a2/>
  <b/><b1/><b2/>
  <c/><c1/><c2/>
</root>"

require 'nokogiri'
xml = Nokogiri::XML(XML)

# Find all elements between 'a' and 'c'
p xml.xpath('//*[preceding-sibling::a][following-sibling::c]').map(&:name)
#=> ["a1", "a2", "b", "b1", "b2"]

# Find all elements between 'a' and 'b'
p xml.xpath('//*[preceding-sibling::a][following-sibling::b]').map(&:name)
#=> ["a1", "a2"]

# Find all elements after 'c'
p xml.xpath('//*[preceding-sibling::c]').map(&:name)
#=> ["c1", "c2"]
```

Now, here it is with your use case (finding by index):

```
HTML = "<h1> Header is here</h1>
  <h2>Header 2 is here</h2>
     <p>Extract me!</p>
     <p>Extract me too!</p>
  <h2> Next Header 2</h2>
     <p>not interested</p>
     <p>not interested</p>
  <h2>Header 2 is here</h2>
     <p>Extract me three!</p>
     <p>Extract me four!</p>"

require 'nokogiri'
html = Nokogiri::HTML(HTML)

# Find all elements between the first and second h2s
p html.xpath('//*[preceding-sibling::h2[1]][following-sibling::h2[2]]').map(&:content)
#=> ["Extract me!", "Extract me too!"]

# Find all elements between the third h2 and the end
p html.xpath('//*[preceding-sibling::h2[3]]').map(&:content)
#=> ["Extract me three!", "Extract me four!"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you, but it stil needed more information about tags location (it's better if you info which needs to be extracted will be located between some tags)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

html = '<h1> Header is here</h1>
  <h2>Header 2 is here</h2>
     <p> Extract me!</p>
     <p> Extract me too!</p>
  <h2> Next Header 2</h2>
     <p>not interested</p>
     <p>not interested</p>
  <h2>Header 2 is here</h2>
     <p> Extract me!</p>
     <p> Extract me too!</p>
';

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html);

doc.xpath("//p").each do |el|
  pp el
end
```