# Extract text based on previous and next sibling

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract data from the following structure:

```
<span>Heading</span>
<br />
<br />
<span>Heading1</span>
<br />
data#1
<br />
<br />
<span>Heading4</span><br />
&acirc;&euro;&cent; data#4.1
<br />
&acirc;&euro;&cent; data#4.2
<br />
&acirc;&euro;&cent; data#4.3
<br />
&acirc;&euro;&cent; data#4.4
<br />
<br />
<span>Heading5</span>
<br />
&acirc;&euro;&cent; data#5.1
<br />
&acirc;&euro;&cent; data#5.2
<br />
&acirc;&euro;&cent; data#5.3
<br />
<br />
```

I can extract data#1 using something like this:

`span[text()='Heading1']/following-sibling::br[1]/following::text()[1]`

But I cant figure out how to extract the data under Heading4. I need to extract `data#4.1`, `data#4.2`, `data#4.3` & `data#4.4`.
The number of points is not fixed and can vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This XPath 1.0 expression selects exactly the wanted nodes**:

```
  /*/span[.='Heading4']
        /following-sibling::text()
           [count(.|/*/span[.='Heading5']/preceding-sibling::text())
           =
            count(/*/span[.='Heading5']/preceding-sibling::text())
            ]
                  [normalize-space()]
```

It is produced from the well-known Kayessian method for intersection of two nodesets `$ns1` and `$ns2`:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

We obtain the first expression above if in the Kayessian formula we substitute `$ns1` with:

```
  /*/span[.='Heading4']/following-sibling::text()
```

and `$ns2` with:

```
  /*/span[.='Heading5']/preceding-sibling::text()
```

The final predicate `[normalize-space()]` filters out the whitespace-only text nodes from this intersection.

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
      "/*/span[.='Heading4']
            /following-sibling::text()
               [count(.|/*/span[.='Heading5']/preceding-sibling::text())
               =
                count(/*/span[.='Heading5']/preceding-sibling::text())
                ]
                [normalize-space()]
      "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (with the entities replaced -- as we don't have a DTD defining them available and this isn't essential here):

```
<html>
    <span>Heading</span>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span>Heading1</span>
    <br /> data#1 
    <br />
    <br />
    <span>Heading4</span>
    <br /> #acirc;#euro;#cent; data#4.1 
    <br /> #acirc;#euro;#cent; data#4.2 
    <br /> #acirc;#euro;#cent; data#4.3 
    <br /> #acirc;#euro;#cent; data#4.4 
    <br />
    <br />
    <span>Heading5</span>
    <br /> #acirc;#euro;#cent; data#5.1 
    <br /> #acirc;#euro;#cent; data#5.2 
    <br /> #acirc;#euro;#cent; data#5.3 
    <br />
    <br />
</html>
```

**the Xpath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
 #acirc;#euro;#cent; data#4.1 
     #acirc;#euro;#cent; data#4.2 
     #acirc;#euro;#cent; data#4.3 
     #acirc;#euro;#cent; data#4.4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
span[text()='Heading4']/following-sibling::text()[. != ""]
```

to get all the text after Heading4 and then use.

```
span[text()='Heading5']/following-sibling::text()[. != ""]
```

to get the text after Heading5 that you don't want, and then subtract the second result set from the first in your main program.

And if you have XPath 2, you can  exclude them directly with the `except` operator:

```
span[text()='Heading4']/following-sibling::text()[. != ""] except span[text()='Heading5']/following::text()[. != ""]
```

You can get only the `data` without the `&acirc;&euro;&cent;` before with the `substring(.,5)` function, so the final XPath 2 expression becomes:

```
(span[text()='Heading4']/following-sibling::text()[. != ""] except span[text()='Heading5']/following::text()[. != ""])/substring(., 5)
```

And since you haven't explicitly said your language requirement you might also want to look at my [pascal based query language](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/htmlparserExampleCGI), because it is imho way much nicer:

```
 <span>Heading4</span><br />
 <t:loop>
    {filter(text(), "data.*")}<br/>
 </t:loop>
 <br/>
 <span>Heading5</span><br />
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Will try it out. Im actually using this in scrapy, which is a python based web scraping framework.

Comment: Just checked, scrapy doesnt support XPath 2.0. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, I have implemented all of XPath 2.0... (i really should have done it in python, but I thought the interpreter memory overhead was too large :( )

You can probably simulate the except operator with the position()/last()/count() functions to exclude a certain number of text nodes. Like this:

`(/span[text()='Heading4']/following::text()[position() < last() - count(/span[text()='Heading5']/following::text())])[.!=""]`

(pressing enter saves the comment? that's annoying. as well as the disappearing line breaks)

Answer (score 1):

I finally ended up using this, with help from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489326/xpath-get-elements-that-are-between-2-elements)

`//text()[preceding-sibling::span[1] = 'Heading4']`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
span[text()='Heading4']/following-sibling::text()
```

and then parse resulting text separately.