# Collect Line after keyword

Tags: regex, scrapy

Im having trouble finding some text in a page. The biggest part is because the location of the text changes between pages.

If I could get some help extracting the line text AFTER the line containing the keyword "Camp Director"

html example:

```
<div class="span4">
                    <strong>Camp Director : </strong>
                                            <span>Camp Directors Name</span>
                                    </div>
```

I was playing around with this:

```
def parse1(self, response):
hxs = Selector(response)
titles = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="fullwidth-container"]')
body = hxs.xpath('/html/body')
items = []

for titles in titles:
    item = BayItem()

    item["director"] = "".join(response.css('#fullwidth-container > div > div > div.geobase.complex-module-container.module > div.geobase-listing > div > div.premium.row-fluid.complex-module-columns-container > div.span8.respond-container.main-block > div.custom-field.geobase-cf-text > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(3) > span').extract())
    item["director1"] = titles.xpath('//*[@id="fullwidth-container"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/span').extract()
    item["director2"] = titles.xpath('//*[@id="fullwidth-container"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/span').extract()
    item["director3"] = titles.xpath('//*[@id="fullwidth-container"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[4]/div[2]/span').extract()
    item["director4"] = re.findall('Camp Director(\*)', response.body)
    converter = html2text.HTML2Text()
    converter.ignore_links = True
    items.append(item)
    return items
```

Im kinda leaning to the fact that i may have to use more regex but im not exactly sure how to use it. So appreciate the help guys!

Comment: Please try: `re.findall('Camp Director.*\n(.*\n)', response.body)`

Answer (score 0):

As long as this format is consistent (meaning there is a new line after the line with "Camp Director" in it) this should work for you:

regex = Camp\sDirector.+strong>\n\s*(.*)

This captures the text in the next line.

Comment: Thanks but how would you fill this into an item so that I can get it. Because when I play around with that I cant get it to show anything.

Comment: You're using Python?
Just define a variable (ie. regex = .....) and then print the group using something like:
print regex.group(1)

Comment: no im using it in scrapy. I;m just very new at it so i think this would work but not for scrapy. my syntax im looking for is something like:

    item["director4"] = re.findall('Camp Director(\*)', response.body)

Comment: Ok, I haven't personally used scrappy, but I just did a quick search and I think you'd be able to figure out how to incorporate the regex code above into your program by looking here:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.12/topics/selectors.html

Comment: Unforunately not sure how to change from @href to text but ill keep looking into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! I found the answer I needed. With help from @AmericanMade and @Dimitre Novatchev on [Extract text based on previous and next sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719583/extract-text-based-on-previous-and-next-sibling)

Final code was:

```
def parse1(self, response):
hxs = Selector(response)
titles = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="fullwidth-container"]')
items = []

for titles in titles:
    item = BayItem()
    item["director"] = response.xpath('//div[contains(text(), "Camp Director : ")]/following-sibling::text()')
    converter = html2text.HTML2Text()
    converter.ignore_links = True
    items.append(item)
    return items
```

Raw line

item["director"] = response.xpath('//div[contains(text(), "Camp Director : ")]/following-sibling::text()')