# Xpath Get elements that are between 2 elements where we can't use an id or text to identify the 2nd tag

Tags: html, xpath, boolean-logic

I have a similar problem to this question [Xpath Get elements that are between 2 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489326/xpath-get-elements-that-are-between-2-elements).  But in my specific case the html can vary and I can't use the text of the second element

Basically I have an  structure like:

```
<h1>Account Information</h1>
<a class="null" href="http:...">Remarks</a>
<a class="null" href="http:...">Owner Information</a>
<b>Account Detail</b>
<a class="null" href="http:...">Industrial</a>

<a class="null" href="http:...">land</a>
<b >Transfers</b>
<a class="null" href="http:...">11111</a>
<a class="null" href="http:...">22222</a>
```

So I want get `<a>` between the b='Account Detail' and the next b that can vary the text.

For this cases I used a version of the [2nd answer of question above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489469/2399444)

```
//a[preceding-sibling::b='Account Detail' and following-sibling::b]
```

for this case works ok because have only one b after the  b='Account Detail'
I got

> [Industrial,land]

But If we have more than one `<b>`after the  b='Account Detail'

But If we have more than one `<b>`

```
<h1>Account Information</h1>
<a class="null" href="http:...">Remarks</a>
<a class="null" href="http:...">Owner Information</a>
<b>Account Detail</b>
<a class="null" href="http:...">Industrial</a>    
<a class="null" href="http:...">land</a>
<b class="">Permits</b>
 <a class="null" href="http:...">12-12-222</a>
 <a class="null" href="http:...">22-2-22</a>
<b >Transfers</b>
<a class="null" href="http:...">11111</a>
<a class="null" href="http:...">22222</a>
```

The result is:

> [Industrial,land,12-12-222,22-2-22]

Which is not the desired behavior

Any advice?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below XPath to get required nodes:

```
//a[preceding-sibling::b[1]='Account Detail' and following-sibling::b]
```

`preceding-sibling::b[1]='Account Detail'` intend to fetch anchor that has no preceding-siblings `<b>` before the one with `'Account Detail'` content

Comment: Woks ok, what is the difference  b[1] or b here?

Comment: `b[1]='Account Detail'` means that the *first* preceding-sibling `b` node has content `'Account Detail'`, so in this case, for example,  `<a>12-12-222</a>` will not be matched as the first preceding-sibling `b` for this anchor has content `"Permits"`. It actually can be simplified to `//a[preceding-sibling::b[1]='Account Detail']`